# Accessing parent controller in dynamically generated AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some items stored in a database. Each item has a 'type'. I want to use this type to dynamically insert a directive based on the type. My html would look like:

```
<ul>
  <li my-item ng-repeat="item in items"></li>
</ul
```

In the `my-item` directive I dynamically generate a directive as follows:

```
app.directive('myItem', function($compile){
    return {
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            var concreteTypeEl = $compile('<div my-item-' + scope.item.type + ' item="item"></div>')(scope);
            el.append(concreteTypeEl);
        }
    };
});
```

And then I have further directives defining the 'concrete' item type. For example an item with type 'Type1' would use the 'myItemType1' directive (shown below)

So that's all fine. Now, I also want a parent directive to wrap all instances of these directives and provide a controller to allow coordination between them.

I use the `require ^parentCtrl` syntax on the `myItem` directive to access the parent controller.

**My problem is that this doesn't work for any of the 'dynamically' inserted directives such as 'myItemType1'**

Full example below and in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IumcTaOYt9oCEKLh0iTN?p=preview). The markup:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div my-container>
        <ul>
            <li my-item ng-repeat="item in items"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

The code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        type: 'type1',
        content: 'Type 1 item'
    }, {
        type: 'type1',
        content: 'Another Type 1 item'
    }];
});

app.directive('myContainer', function(){
    return {
        controller: function() {
            this.doSomething = function() {
                return 'foo';
            }
        }
    };
});

app.directive('myItem', function($compile){
    return {
        require: '^myContainer',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, myContainer) {

            // 'myContainer' is a reference to parent controller
            console.log('Ctrl in myItem:', myContainer);

            var concreteTypeEl = $compile('<div my-item-' + scope.item.type + ' item="item"></div>')(scope);
            el.append(concreteTypeEl);
        }
    };
});

app.directive('myItemType1', function($compile){
    return {
        require: '?^myContainer',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, myContainer) {

            // PROBLEM: 'myContainer' is undefined here
            console.log('Ctrl in myItemType1:', myContainer);

            el.append(scope.item.content);
        }
    };
});
```

Am I approaching this all wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should append the element to the DOM tree before you manually compile and link it:

```
link:function(scope,element,attr) {
    // create the element
    var e = angular.element('<my-child></my-child>');           
    //append it to the DOM  
    element.append(e);
    // compile and link
    $compile(e)(scope);
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7JwrW/1/)